# Cisco switch can't log off VTY user

Tags: cisco

I have a Cisco 3821 switch sitting on the edge that has 4 connections from China that can't be booted off.

```
c3821:#sh users
...
  12 vty 11               idle                    1y40w cm-114-109-36-18.revip13.asianet.co.th
  13 vty 12               idle                    1y40w cm-114-109-36-18.revip13.asianet.co.th
  14 vty 13               idle                    1y40w cm-114-109-36-18.revip13.asianet.co.th
  15 vty 14               idle                    1y40w cm-114-109-36-18.revip13.asianet.co.th
  16 vty 15               idle                    1y40w cm-114-109-36-18.revip13.asianet.co.th
```

I try to kill the connection using:

```
c3821#clear line vty 12
[confirm]y [OK]
c3821#sh users
    Line       User       Host(s)              Idle       Location
  ...
  12 vty 11               idle                    1y40w cm-114-109-36-18.revip13.asianet.co.th
  13 vty 12               idle                    1y40w cm-114-109-36-18.revip13.asianet.co.th
  14 vty 13               idle                    1y40w cm-114-109-36-18.revip13.asianet.co.th
  15 vty 14               idle                    1y40w cm-114-109-36-18.revip13.asianet.co.th
  16 vty 15               idle                    1y40w cm-114-109-36-18.revip13.asianet.co.th
```

My questions:

1. Is this anything to worry about?
2. How can I actually get rid of those connections (without rebooting the switch)?

Comment: That's Thailand, not China.

Comment: You can try: `sh tcp brief` to find out the TCB number and then `clear tcp tcb tcb_number` to clear up.

Comment: @JohnP, I have put it as an answer. Have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like TCP sync flooding attack.

You need to find out the TCB numbers to be able to clear the sessions.

> The Transmission Control Block (TCB) is a transport protocol data
>   structure (actually a set of structures in many operations systems)
>   that holds all the information about a connection. The memory
>   footprint of a single TCB depends on what TCP options and other
>   features an implementation provides and has enabled for a connection.
>   Usually, each TCB exceeds at least 280 bytes, and in some operating
>   systems currently takes more than 1300 bytes. The TCP SYN-RECEIVED
>   state is used to indicate that the connection is only half open, and
>   that the legitimacy of the request is still in question. The important
>   aspect to note is that the TCB is allocated based on reception of the
>   SYN packet— before the connection is fully established or the
>   initiator's return reachability has been verified.

Source and details: [Defenses Against TCP SYN Flooding Attacks](http://www.cisco.com/web/about/ac123/ac147/archived_issues/ipj_9-4/syn_flooding_attacks.html).

To find out the TCB number use:

`show tcp brief`

And to clear the sessions:

`clear tcp tcb tcb_number`